# Scala actors & Ambient Reference

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In [Phillip Haller's PhD thesis](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/151999/files/EPFL_TH4874.pdf) he mentioned in section (5.1 Future Work) that one of the interesting areas of research would be to extend the framework with ambient references and he cited Van Cutsen's paper.

Excerpt:

> The Scala Actors library includes a runtime system that provides basic
>   support for remote (i.e., inter-VM) actor communication. To provide
>   support for fault tolerancy (for instance, in mobile ad-hoc networks),
>   it would be interesting to extend the framework with remote actor
>   references that support volatile connections, similar to ambient
>   references [36]. Integrating transactional abstractions for
>   fault-tolerant distributed programming (e.g., [52, 142]) into Scala
>   Actors is another interesting area for future work.

And citated paper is:

> [36] Tom Van Cutsem, Jessie Dedecker, Stijn Mostinckx, Elisa Gonzalez
>   Boix, Theo D’Hondt, and Wolfgang De Meuter. Ambient references:
>   addressing objects in mobile networks. [...] pages 986–997. ACM, October
>   2006.

Is this what Akka did? If not, do you think it is still relevant to research this area given the fact that Akka exists today?

Comment: Could you add a link to the thesis paper?

Comment: Why was this question closed? It's within the scope defined in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with Akka.

There are 2 ways to achieve this as far as I know:

1. [akka-remote](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html) - Provides remote actor ref, but you need to decide where each actor should exsist.
2. [akka-cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-sharding.html) - Provides cluster sharding. Automatically manages actor physical location and ensures that given shard (Actor) is present on **at most one** node in the cluster.